# javascript example to remove .htm from a web page

Tags: javascript, html, regex, arrays, match

I have some client side Javascript that adds the file size and an icon for .doc, pdf and csv files that uses arrays and the .push method. I wanted to amend the code to remove .htm from page urls. Here is my code within a function called getAnchorTags:

```
splitAndJoinArray.push([matches[a],{orig:matches[a],modified:"<img class ='MIME_content' src='" + getMIMEImage(href)+ "' alt='" + getMIMEAlt(href) + "'>" + matches[a] + " (" + getFileType(href) + getFileSize(href) + "kb)"}]);
```

This works fine using .push to add items to the end of the array. I have tried and failed using .replace to remove the .htm from all page urls:

```
splitAndJoinArray.replace([/.htm/g,{orig:matches2[a],modified:""}]);
```

Matches and matches2 use some regex to get the required file extensions:

```
var matches = str.match( /<a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']*([^"]*?\.(pdf|ppt|csv|xls|doc))[\"\']*.*?>([^<]+|.*?)?/gi);
var matches2 = str.match( /<a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']*([^"]*?\.(htm))[\"\']*.*?>([^<]+|.*?)?/gi);
```

matches2 works OK and returns a list of the htm links on the page.  Because this is something I have inherited and my JavaScript isn't really up to much I do not know how to change

```
splitAndJoinArray.replace([/.htm/g,{orig:matches2[a],modified:""}]);
```

which i know is incorrect to strip off the .htm.  I can add more code if that would help.

Comment: You mean splitAndJoinArray.push([matches2[a].replace(".htm","")....

Comment: thanks for that mplungjan - will try it in the morning.  It's been a really long day.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks mplungjan.  That almost worked.  After some minor tinkering with your solution I amended it to: splitAndJoinArray.push([matches2[a],{orig:matches2[a],modified:matches2[a].replace(".htm","")}]);

Answer (score 0):

mplungjan pointed me in the right direction.  The following strips the .htm from the page source:

```
splitAndJoinArray.push([matches2[a],{orig:matches2[a],modified:matches2[a].replace(".htm","")}]);
```

Comment: Ok. So the code [matches2[a].replace(".htm","") was what you needed